# whwn i start run expo i get Error: GetEnv.NoBoolean: ture is not a boolean

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, yarnpkg

```
    $ expo start
    C:\Users\Amoory\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\getenv\lib\getenv.js:66
             throw new Error('GetEnv.NoBoolean: ' + value + ' is not a boolean.');
              ^

          Error: GetEnv.NoBoolean: ture is not a boolean.
    at Object.boolish (C:\Users\Amoory\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\getenv\lib\getenv.js:66:15)
    at Function.boolish (C:\Users\Amoory\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\getenv\lib\getenv.js:79:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Amoory\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js:17:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info 

Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

C:\Users\Amoory\Desktop\omar-1>

Comment: You have a typo somewhere, `ture` instead of `true`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `ture` to `true` in your environment variables which are loaded using `GetEnv`

Comment: the code is right [link]( https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/631ec0bc-0504-4f2e-a323-2328cb8bd504 )